# Given any equivalence $\sim$ on $X$ do functions $f:X\to X$ such that $f(u)=f(v)\iff u\sim v$ have a specific name?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations, monoid

Given any equivalence $\sim$ on $X$ do functions $f:X\to X$ such that $f(u)=f(v)\iff u\sim v$ have a specific name?

I know if I replace the image of each element with its pre-image then this is called a canonical projection map of $\sim$.

Also that this set of functions $S$ forms a sub-monoid $M=(S,\circ,\text{id}_X)$ of the complete transformation monoid on $X$ (the monoid of all functions mapping elements from $X$ to $X$).

Comment: If you require $f(u)=f(v)$ if $u\sim v$, then they are functions that “factor through” the quotient. If you require that $f(u)=f(v)\iff u\sim v$, then they are functions of the form $\psi\circ \pi$, where $\pi\colon X\to X/\sim$ is the porjection onto the quotient, and $\psi$ is a bijection.

Comment: Actually, such functions do not form a submonoid unless $\sim$ coincides with equality (the identity is not such a function). At least, if we merely require that $u \sim v$ implies $f(u)=f(v)$, then such functions would simultaneously form a left ideal in the monoid of all functions $X \to X$ and a right ideal in the monoid of functions satisfying the weaker property that $u \sim v$ implies $f(u) \sim f(v)$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that in fact *any function* $f:X\to Y$ determines an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$ as follows: for all $x,x' \in X$,

$$x \sim x' :\Leftrightarrow f(x) = f(x').$$

That implies that *any function* with $\sim$ given as above has a *natural decomposition* (*) $$ X\xrightarrow{p} (X/\sim) \xrightarrow{\overline{f}} f(X) \xrightarrow{i} Y$$ such that $f = i\circ \overline{f}\circ p$ (unfortunately i can't draw any commutative diagram via mathjax).

In the diagram above $p$ is the natural projection, $\overline{f}$ is a bijection defined by $\overline{f}([x]) = f(x)$ and $i$ is the inclusion $f(X)\subset Y$.

You'll notice that if $f$ is surjective, the diagram simplifies to

$$ X\xrightarrow{p} (X/\sim) \xrightarrow{\overline{f}}  Y.$$

(*) this might be the term you were looking for.